# how to create python class to create object on init

Tags: python

i need to create the following object in python

```
ldapdict = {
      'objectclass': [b'inetOrgPerson', b'person'],
      'cn': [b'George Orwell'],
      'givenName': [b'George'],
      'sn': [b'Orwell'],
      'uidNumber': [b'1984'],
      'gidNumber': [b'1984'],
      'mail': [
      b'george.orwell@example.com',
      b'big.brother@example.com',
  ],
  }
```

I have the following code but it is not working and i cannot figure it out

```
cat ./main.py
#!/usr/bin/python

from ldap import LdapEntry

#ldapdict = {
#      'objectclass': [b'inetOrgPerson', b'person'],
#      'cn': [b'George Orwell'],
#      'givenName': [b'George'],
#      'sn': [b'Orwell'],
#      'uidNumber': [b'1984'],
#      'gidNumber': [b'1984'],
#      'mail': [
#      b'george.orwell@example.com',
#      b'big.brother@example.com',
#  ],
#  }

ldapdict = dict()

e = LdapEntry(ldapdict)

assert(e.cn == 'George Orwell')
assert(e.uidNumber == 1984)
assert('big.brother@example.com' in e.mail)
assert(len(e.mail) == 2)


cat ldap.py
#!/usr/bin/python

class LdapEntry:

    my_dict = {'objectclass':''}

    def __init__(self, objects):
        self.objectclass = objects.objectclass
        self.cn = objects.cn
        self.givenName = objects.givenName
        self.sn = objects.sn
        self.uidNumber = objects.uidNumber
        self.gidNumber = objects.gidNumber
        self.mail = objects.mail
```

It errors with

```
./main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./main.py", line 20, in <module>
    e = LdapEntry(ldapdict)
  File "/home/ec2-user/ldap.py", line 8, in __init__
    self.objectclass = objects.objectclass
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'objectclass'
```

**UPDATE**

so i changed it like so

```
self.objectclass = ['inetOrgPerson','person']
        self.cn = 'George Orwell'
        self.givenName = 'George'
        self.sn = 'Orwell'
        self.uidNumber = '1984'
        self.gidNumber = '1984'
        self.mail = ['george.orwell@example.com', 'big.brother@example.com']
```

but it errors with

```
$ ./main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./main.py", line 23, in <module>
    assert(e.uidNumber == 1984)
AssertionError
```

Comment: You need to be more specific than "not working". What does it do wrong. Why do you have the dictionary commented out?

Comment: The dictionary contains byte strings, but you're comparing them with ordinary strings.

Comment: Actually, now you are passing an *empty dict*. So it's totally unclear to me what you are expecting to happen or how any of this is supposed to work...

Comment: Other commenters have made some good points, I think you're misunderstanding something about classes.